# React application not loading on IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, babel-polyfill

I am getting the below error in console of IE11 -

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'nextEffect' of undefined or null reference.
```

I am using `6.26.0` version of `babel-polyfill`.

I have added `babel-polyfill` in webpack.config.js.

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js']
```

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: Yes, could not figure out the issue

Comment: telepathic support on way - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11583

Comment: checked the link

Answer (score 0):

Please try https://www.jianshu.com/p/3b27dfc6785c:(no more -1 pls)
Global babel-polyfill (do not use useBuiltIns)
Instructions
Method 3.1: (Browser Environment) is introduced separately in the html tag babel-polyfill.js(both CDN or local file)
Method 3.2: package.jsonAdd babel-polyfilldependencies in, webpackadd entries in the configuration file: eg entry: ["babel-polyfill",'./src/app.js'], polyfill will be packaged into this entry file, and placed at the very beginning of the file
Method 3.3: package.jsonAdd babel-polyfilldependencies in, webpackuse the import/requireintroduction at the top of the entry file , such as `import 'babel-polyfill'``